# How to hide progressbar in Android?

Tags: android, visibility, android-progressbar

I added a progressbar to my app but I want to hide it after some doing some action,

I used `hide()`, `dismiss()` and `cancel()`... but none of them work?

How can I hide the progressbar?

Comment: Please mention the class you are using. I assume it is: android.widget.ProgressBar, but it does not have hide(), dismiss() or cancel() methods. Have you tried View.GONE. Your question is very old.

Answer (score 34):

```
ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

should be enough.

Edit: fixed typo.

Comment: what a bout Dialog ?! how we can do that ?? it don't have setVisibilty()

Comment: Do you have a ProgressDialog, or a ProgressBar??

Comment: you have a typo: should be setVisibil >i< ty

Answer (score 5):

"all of them are work", that sounds like it means that they work? But then why the question?

I'd say: get the view, en do

```
 myView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Comment: but I assume setVisibility does?

Answer (score 3):

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progressBar.setVisibility(0);    --visible
progressBar.setVisibility(4);    --invisible
progressBar.setVisibility(8);    --gone (like dismiss)
```

Comment: Why not `progressBar.setVisibility(View.Visible);` instead of using these magic numbers?

Answer (score 3):

**KOTLIN**

```
progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
```

Comment: this is the real kotlin version `progressBar.isVisible = false`

Answer (score 1):

when you want to show it
progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

---

when you want to hide it
1 progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
2 progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

Answer (score 0):

1). first make a variable to access progress bar =>
ProgressBar progBar;

2). Initialize it to id given to the progressbar view =>
progBar = findViewById(R.id.ID_OF_PROGRESS_BAR);

3). Now, set the visibility =>
progBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

full code =>

```
ProgressBar progBar;
progBar = findViewById(R.id.ID_OF_PROGRESS_BAR);
progBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```